# What is more appropriate in this sentence - both or each?

Tags: word-choice, verb-agreement

> Communication and interpersonal skills are ________ important in their own ways.

The above sentence is a GATE 2014 MCQ Question with the following options -

- both
- each
- all
- either

The options 'all' and 'either' are certainly not the answer. I am convinced that 'both' is the right answer. I have doubts whether 'each' is equally right or not.

I have read the distinction between both and each [in this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41816/each-vs-both) but I don't understand how to use the knowledge here.

The doubt is due to [this question about is/are each.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232655/is-each-or-are-each)

Comment: If you take skills as plural count (unusual with 'interpersonal', but I can't see how it can be classed as incorrect [see for instance [uk.indeed.com/career-advice ... interpersonal skills](https://uk.indeed.com/career-advice/cvs-cover-letters/interpersonal-skills) {Some examples of interpersonal skills include:}]) 'all' comes into play, though it would normally be sentence-initial here.  // Arguably, neither (a) nor (b) is grammatical, the correct formulation being 'Communication and interpersonal skills are both important, each in its own ways.' But notional agreement is complex here.

Comment: The sentence works with no additional words.

Comment: The last two don't work, but the first two do. To summarize: both are correct; each is correct. As noted, not using a quantifier is acceptable also.

Comment: I think the question setter overreached himself here in an attempt to ask a hard question. I suppose— and it's a mere guess— that he thought only **both** fits here because **each** takes a singular noun/pronoun after it. But that's not how he's framed the question

Comment: As we can see on ESU.SE, English language exam questions worldwide are pretty pathetic. But who cares?